# Javascript Drop and Bounce Effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, drop-down-menu

I can't seem to find a javascript(jQuery or other) effect that works like I want it to. I was hoping someone can help me out.

I am working on a project that has 3 content boxes wrapped within a larger div. I am thinking of adding a "Get A Quote" *button that will take the larger surrounding div and drop it when you click on the "Get A Quote"* (think scooby doo(pull book out of bookcase and the wall drops)) and have it *bounce when it hits like it actually has weight*. Then go back up after the user has filled out the "Get A Quote" form.

I hope that makes a marginal bit of sense.
Just ask if you would like clarification or if you would like me to post a sketch of how it works.

Comment: So uhh...What have to tried so far? You know that jquery has an animate method that can do this for you, right? Have you tried using that?

Comment: Just to make sure we're on the same page, [here's an easing demo](http://www.robertpenner.com/easing/easing_demo.html). Can you go there, scroll down the menu and select `Math.easeOutBounce`, and let us know whether or not that's what you're looking for? Maybe I misunderstood the question.

Comment: @sdleihssirhc The .easeOutBounce is exactly what I was looking for. Maybe this drawing might help. http://stashbox.org/1070306/Screen%20shot%202011-02-19%20at%202.07.06%20PM.png

Comment: @sdleihssirhc Tell me if I'm on the right track: Use the jQuery UI .easeOutBounce on the larger (covering) div but instead of shrinking have it drop straight down and have different content on another z-index layer that is directly below the content that was dropped?

Comment: @Taylor Sounds good, but it's hard to tell without seeing an example. Maybe you could throw together a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/)?

Comment: @sdleihssirhc http://www.threepixeldrift.com/projects/twoglassgents-SO/ The area I am working on dropping is the testimonials and the contact information. It is incased in a #bottom-wrapper div. The subscribe to the newsletter form is going to become one large button.

Comment: @sdleihssirhc If that doesn't make sense I can throw together a JSBin but I think this will make more sense if you can see it in real website form.

Comment: @Taylor What happens if you try to implement the UI/z-index idea you had?

Comment: I'll try it. I'll report back a bit later.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is an already available feature in JQuery UI. http://jqueryui.com/demos/show/. 
This is how you do it

```
<style type="text/css">
#mydiv{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background:red;
    display:none;
    margin-top:30px;
}
</style>

<button>clickme</button>
<div id="mydiv"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('button').click(function(){
    $('#mydiv').toggle('bounce',300)
});
</script>
```

### You can see a working example at http://jsfiddle.net/TUFaw/

I used toggle which means if you click on the button again, the effect will be revered back to hide the box. You can use many of the available effect (blind, clip, drop, explode, fold, highlight, puff, pulsate, shake, slide, size, scale)

If you never worked with jQuery before, make sure you include the required CSS and JS files.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/themes/start/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: @taylor consider accepting the answer to give credit where credit is due.

Comment: Thanks, this explained it well.

Comment: Sorry for the extremely slow response, I've been so busy.